# Scrape url instead of base64 string from src attribute of img tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am fairly new to web scraping and trying to **scrape** a website using Beautifulsoup4 and requests in Python. The page contains one main image and other small alternate images.

While inspecting the required main img tag through browser, the src attribute is a valid url but while fetching the same page through python requests, the src attribute comes as a base64 string. Something like this

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/2wBDAQoLCw4NDhwQEBw7KCIoOzs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozv ...`

src attribute of all other alternate images is coming in proper url form. The problem is only with main image. Is there a way to get the actual url displayed in browser instead of this base64 string ?

Comment: Have a look for base64 in the Python help file.